# What is wrong with this pandas code?

Tags: python, pandas, series

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
s2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6])
s1.append(s2)
print(s1)
```

Such a simple thing but Its not appending. Out up is :
0 1
1 2
2 3
dtype: int64
It just prints s1. Its not appending? What silly mistake am I doing here?

Comment: You need to reassign to s1.  Append is not an "inplace" operation.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `.append` returns a new series, it doesn't mutate in place (like `list.append`). Try:

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
s2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6])
s3 = s1.append(s2)
print(s3)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
s2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6])
s1 = s1.append(s2)
print(s1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The append function returns a new object, instead of modifying the object calling it. Most pandas functions are not 'in place' by default, meaning they return a new object (some allow you to specify to do the operation in place, but append is not one of them).

Instead, you can just reassign s1:

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
s2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6])
s1 = s1.append(s2)
print(s1)
```